# Unable to import pcl in conda

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda

I have installed python-pcl| using pip. When I try to import pcl in my conda environment I am getting the following

**ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/is/sg2/ghegde/install/conda/envs/deepl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pcl/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ._pcl import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcl_visualization.so.1.8: undefined symbol: _ZN3pcl9PCDWriter10writeASCIIERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKNS_14PCLPointCloud2ERKN5Eigen6MatrixIfLi4ELi1ELi0ELi4ELi1EEERKNSC_10QuaternionIfLi0EEEi
```

Comment: Please share the contents of the Conda environment.